# Remove account from ethsign

Tags: accounts, dapptools, ethsign

I am using `ethsign` from the dapptools suite, and I have a private key imported that I can see with `ethsign ls`. How do I remove it?

For example, go from:

```bash
$ ethsign ls
0x3DF02ac6fEe39B79654AA81C6573732439e73A81 keystore
0x643315C9Be056cDEA171F4e7b2222a4ddaB9F88D keystore
```

To:

```
$ ethsign ls
0x643315C9Be056cDEA171F4e7b2222a4ddaB9F88D keystore
```

Answer (score 0):

Default directory is `$HOME/.ethereum/keystore/`

Be sure to create a backup. Delete the file there.

Comment: hmm... not seeing a `.ethereum` folder...